# css - how to vertically align a child div inside a parent div relative to the browser screen?

Tags: javascript, css

how to *vertically align* a **child** `div` *inside* a **parent** `div` relative to the browser screen ?

Please tell me how to do this? I will be very grateful.

You can use *css* and *javascript*.

Below I have attached a picture for a complete understanding of what I want to do.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `sticky` position ? Take a look : https://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/QYLEdK

Comment: No, I haven't tried it. Interesting.